# Apache "Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost."

Tags: apache, ssl, segmentation-fault

First of all, my thanks to this community for helping me solve many, many issues over the years.  In fact, I have never needed to post a new question - I was always able to find an answer (eventually).

Not so this time.  I am a moderately experienced hobby developer, self-hosting a small set of sites on my Mac Mini (Apache 2.4, PHP 8.0, MySQL 5.6).  I built a reasonably complex site ([www.fundas.us/manhattanzen](http://www.fundas.us/manhattanzen)) and everything was working perfectly.

I then decided to add SSL encryption to my server (certificate purchased from ssl.com) and installed it with no issues.  Checking the SSL configuration via "SSL Checker" and Whynopadlock.com confirms that the certificate is properly installed.  The only "warning" I get is that I only have TLSv1 enabled on the server.  This despite the fact that my httpd-ssl.conf file says "SSLProtocol -all SSLv3". I mention this in case it is the cause of my troubles.

The issue I am experiencing is that the SSL encrypted site works perfectly using Firefox and Chrome on the Mac Mini (Mojave), but fails using Safari on the same Mac and fails using any of the browsers on my iPad or iPhone.  Safari's web console shows "Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost." and the server log shows "child pid XXXXX exit signal Segmentation fault (11)".

The resources that fail to load are some (but not all) of the css and js resources that reside on the local (Mac Mini) server.  All other resources (residing on external servers) load fine.

I have tried a number of suggestions found on Stack Overflow, including

- changing file permissions to 777 on the offending resources (js, css files)
- setting KeepAlive to Off in httpd-default.conf
- minifying offending resource files
- increasing SSLSessionCache in httpd-ssl.conf

None of it has made any difference.  I should also point out that I have configured .htaccess in the root folder of my site to force all incoming connections to https://

This seems like the last hurdle to make this website fully encrypted and fully functional and I am thoroughly stuck.  I will appreciate any pointers you have for me.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure this out and wanted to answer my own question, in case it helps anybody else.

First, the strange test results from SSL validation sites that my server was not TLSv1.2 ready.  I fixed this by changing the SSLProtocol line in httpd-ssl.conf to explicitly only permit TLSv1.2 ("SSLProtocol all -SSLv3" --> "SSLProtocol TLSv1.2")

Second, the odd behavior of Safari (on both desktop and mobile) occasionally hanging unable to load a page (while other browsers had no issues).  I found the solution to this at https://serverfault.com/questions/937253/https-doesnt-work-with-safari.  Making the recommended change to httpd-ssl.conf and adding the line "Header unset Upgrade" solved the Safari issue.